# In relational tables, Do I have to write separate queries for each to perform CUD operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and trying to understand how a CUD operation works with two relational tables.

I want to check if I am doing this correctly. At the moment, I am writing a separate query for each table to perform a CUD operation.

Is this is appropriate? or is there a better way?

Also, Does the tables automatically add relationship identifier data to the relationship column in the tables?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  What are you trying to do?  What do the tables look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It maybe unclear, but don't know way to phrase it. I'm trying to validate that the method I am using for CUD is appropriate or not. Each of my tables has columns and a unique identifier and linked the table relationship using that unique identifier.

Comment: As Gordon says, what's correct/appropriate depends entirely on the specific circumstances of what tasks you're trying to perform and what your data structure is

Comment: @ADyson I implied my-self as a newbie and the data structure is a simple one with two tables. Each table connected by it own UID.  It's okay to down vote.

Comment: Your question is really about designing application logic and not about "learning tsql". Insert, Update, and Delete statements affect a single table (generally) so to change the content of multiple tables requires multiple statements. You should focus on learning the complexities of tsql first and not worry about how you package or structure your logic. For Q2 - no, you must provide the values for foreign keys when inserting or updating.

Comment: @sqlbie I didn't downvote you... but my statement still stands. If you'd prefer not to hear what's being said, I can't really do anything about that. There may be more than one way to achieve your specific goals. I'm thinking of triggers, cascading deletes and that sort of thing. But it depends on the business logic of the application. Just saying you want to do CUD and asking if it's correct to do a single statement isn't specific enough.

Comment: All queries which don't read the data will do create, update or delete of some sort, it's the generic basis on which you can build some more interesting logic which is useful to your specific application

Comment: @ADyson I was specific in first place. See, I wrote "Relational tables" in title. I was not sure how this thing works in relational tables.

Comment: @SMor  Thank for the clarification For the Q2, I was using OutSystems and It's SQL. They don't have this foreign key. function.  All I have to do is to link the tables based on relationship (One-One, One-Many, Many-Many).  But I was not clear whether the A Table's UID column data get reflected on the B table's UID column which has relationship with A's table .

Comment: @SMor  What's point of relational database technology if I have to do CUD by writing separate query of each table?

Comment: "I was not sure how this thing works in relational tables"...again it depends on the exact outcome required. You seem to be under the impression your question is specific. It isn't.

Comment: "What's point of relational database technology"...to define relationships between your data entities. The biggest advantage comes in SELECT queries where you can find rows which are linked to each other and output both at once. (e.g. get all employees who are members of a specific department, based on the employee having the relevant department ID in a column in the employee table). In CUD terms, if you wanted to easily delete a department, for example, you could set cascading deletes so that you didn't have to separately delete all the related employees first. I mentioned this concept before

Comment: "It's SQL. They don't have this foreign key"...then you aren't using SQL Server, as per your tag. But then again I can't think of any other database system which _doesn't_ have foreign keys...unless it's actually a NoSQL database such as MongoDB or something. I'm pretty sure your database _does_ have the ability to create foreign keys, if it's a SQL Server database. All relational database systems do.

Comment: @ADyson So the biggest advantage goes to Data Selection/Reading, Right? 

If so, I could say my current approach for CUD is appropriate even though I'm not confident.

Comment: @ADyson They seems use the ID as a foreign key. It's a visual programming system so things bit different.

Comment: It'll still be creating those relationships under the hood, it's just a GUI to help you manage it.

Comment: "seems use the ID as a foreign key"...what ID? It's unclear what you mean. This is another reason we keep asking you for specific examples. We can't see your screen, and we're not mind-readers. In the department/employees example I used, you would have Department table with "DepartmentID" and "Name" columns. Then you have Employee table with "EmployeeID", "Name" and "DepartmentID" columns. The foreign key relationship would be between "DepartmentID" in both tables. DepartmentID in the Employee table would be a Foreign Key to DepartmentID in the Employee table.

Comment: This would then enable you to write something like `SELECT Employee.Name, Department.Name FROM Employee INNER JOIN Department ON Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID` which would get you a list of every employee and the name of the department they belong to.

Comment: @ADyson   The ID is the ID of the row (It automatically generate an ID for each row in the table). It's not the other ID's.  Simply it's called ID.   We have an ID column besides other ID's like Employee ID

Comment: @ADyson So the biggest advantage in relational database goes for Data Selection not CUD. Right?

Comment: It's a bit strange to use the primary ID of a table as the foreign key to another table. That can only ever create a one-to-one type of relationship, which usually isn't very useful..and what do you mean "they" seem to use it? Surely you yourself get to choose the relationship you want when you design your tables??

Comment: @ADyson  I can simply drag and link then create relationship. The system automatically create an another ID like "UserID" on that table.

So it's always follow  "TableName.ID" syntax when creating a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must write a separate query for each table in order to perform the CUD operation. A foreign key ensures data integrity and cannot reflect primary key data unless you perform the ON UPDATE CASCADE operation, but if the primary key data is automatically incremented, you really do not need to perform the ON UPDATE CASCADE operation. You can perform the ON UPDATE CASCADE operation if your primary key data contains business values, such as tracking numbers, that do not automatically increase.